# Can't get span to correctly display as block?

Tags: css, block, html

I'm trying to have my span begin a new line on overflow; It seems very trivial, but I just can't seem to make it work.

I am aware that it is by default inline, so I am trying to set it to block. I have tried both changing the css display, as well as applying `clear: both` in case any outside css is affecting it, but I still can't get it to display properly. I've made a fiddle to show my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/QUpPn/

Thanks.

Comment: Why the down vote, I don't see any problem with this question

Comment: You should show an example of actual text content, not sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdffsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsf. The correct answer depends on the content. Without disclosing real content, you’ll probably get just snake-oil answers.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Well I've certainly realized that now- it was what was causing my bug in the first place, so I'm not likely to repeat it. Learning means recognizing your mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem of **span**. Use **word-wrap:break-word;** for this. Write like this:

```
#test {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QUpPn/1/

Comment: Well shoot; My actual text is going to include spaces, but I was just using that as a precursor to test it. Perhaps I should use spaces in my tests from now on! Regardless, the word wrap is useful to know; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply just add `word-wrap:break-word;` to your `#test` class.
 And also you can use `text-align:justify;` to make the text better view.
 **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/QUpPn/2/)**